# How can I write the output of this code straight to .CSV file?

Tags: c++

How can I write the output of this code straight to .CSV file?
I want to generate the output straight to the .CSV file.

Thanks for the help!

I just want to get all this combinations in to the .CSV file.

Please help.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Program to print all combination of size r in an array of size n
#include <stdio.h>
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end, 
                    int index, int r);

// The main function that prints all combinations of size r
// in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil()
void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r)
{
    // A temporary array to store all combination one by one
    int data[r];

    // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]'
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
}

/* arr[] ---> Input Array
data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination
start & end ---> Staring and Ending indexes in arr[]
index ---> Current index in data[]
r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end,
                    int index, int r)
{
    // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
    if (index == r)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
            printf("%d ", data[j]);
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    // replace index with all possible elements. The condition
    // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element
    // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
    // at remaining positions
    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
    {
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int r = 5;
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printCombination(arr, n, r);

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Wrtie it to a file in what way?  What goes on each line?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `.csv` file is a comma-separated values stored in plain text. 
So you can instead of `printf`-ing just write output in a `.csv` file.

**Example:**
Instead of: `printf("%d ", data[j]);` and `printf("\n");`
Write: `csv_file << data[j] << ", ";` and `csv_file << "\n";`

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) tutorial will teach you how to read and write from a file.

Or (**2nd solution**) you can redirect the comma-separated output to a `*csv` file. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file).